# How to find all the rows that have identical content and delete content from one of them using special condition?

Tags: mysql

So I have table that has next structure:

```
id | part_id | lang | title | alias | content
```

So lang column can be different, for example **lang_1**,**lang_2**,**lang_3** etc., but the content can be identical.

So the question is how to I make a query that compares rows only that are of certain `lang` for example **lang_2** and **lang_3** and have identical `content`? And then If it finds any it deletes any text that is inside of the `content` column where `lang` == ***lang_3**

So far I came up with something like this:

```
select 
    *
from
    mytable
where
    lang like 'lang_2'
        or lang like 'lang_3' and content != ''
        and content in (select 
            content
        from
            mytable
        group by content
        having count(*) > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try do this:

```
UPDATE myTable
set content = NULL
from myTable A
inner join myTable AA on A.content = AA.content
where A.lang = 'lang_3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following SQl query:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE MT1
INNER JOIN MYTABLE MT2
ON MT1.ID != MT2.ID AND MT1.CONTENT = MT2.CONTENT
SET MT1.CONTENT = NULL
WHERE MT1.LANG = 'lang_1'
```

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16a8f/1)

**Note**: This SQL query is good if you want to update only one type of language.